# How to pause the animation

Tags: javascript, html

I make this image move around the canvas but none of the methods stop it from moving.I make the setInterval to make the move and clear the Interval later by clearInterval in order to stop the motion but seems it won't work

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      var ctx = null;
      var x_icon = 0;
      var y_icon = 0;
      var stepX = 1;
      var stepY = 1;
      var size_x = 221;
      var size_y = 184;
      var canvas_size_x = 800;
      var canvas_size_y = 600;
      var anim_img = null;



      function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        anim_img = new Image(size_x, size_y);
        anim_img.onload = function() { 
            var myvar = setInterval(myAnimation, 10); 
            function stopMove() {
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }

        }
        anim_img.src = 'image/download.jpg';
      }

      function myAnimation() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_size_x, canvas_size_y);
       if (x_icon < 0 || x_icon > canvas_size_x - size_x) {stepX = -stepX; }
       if (y_icon < 0 || y_icon > canvas_size_y - size_y) {stepY = -stepY; }
          x_icon += stepX;
          y_icon += stepY;
       ctx.drawImage(anim_img, x_icon, y_icon);
      }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:solid 1px;"></canvas>
    <button onmousedown="stopMove()">STOP</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected to stop the motion of the download.jpg on click of the STOP button but it won't work

Comment: It is because `stopMove()` only exists within the context of `draw()`, and not in the global namespace, and hence cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

As @Snel23 said, you need to lift `stopMove()` and `myvar` out from the `draw()` context.

```
  var ctx = null;
  var x_icon = 0;
  var y_icon = 0;
  var stepX = 1;
  var stepY = 1;
  var size_x = 221;
  var size_y = 184;
  var canvas_size_x = 800;
  var canvas_size_y = 600;
  var anim_img = null;
  var myvar = null; // moving interval handle outside draw()



  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    anim_img = new Image(size_x, size_y);
    anim_img.onload = function() 
    { 
        myvar = setInterval(myAnimation, 10);  
    }
    anim_img.src = 'image/download.jpg';
  }
  function stopMove() {
      clearInterval(myVar);
  }


  function myAnimation() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_size_x, canvas_size_y);
   if (x_icon < 0 || x_icon > canvas_size_x - size_x) {stepX = -stepX; }
   if (y_icon < 0 || y_icon > canvas_size_y - size_y) {stepY = -stepY; }
      x_icon += stepX;
      y_icon += stepY;
   ctx.drawImage(anim_img, x_icon, y_icon);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your interval (which you call `myVar`) at the top level of your code (outside of your functions) and also move your nested function out to the top level, you can access both of them as needed, something like:

```js
// Defines global identifiers
let
  ctx = null,
  x_icon = 0,
  y_icon = 0,
  stepX = 1,
  stepY = 1,
  size_x = 260,
  size_y = 175,
  canvas_size_x = 400,
  canvas_size_y = 180,
  anim_img = null,
  interval = null; // `interval` is a global variable

const
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  button = document.getElementById("button");

// Calls `stop` when the user clicks the button
button.addEventListener("click", stop);

// Calls `draw` immediately to render the initial canvas
draw();


function draw() {
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  anim_img = new Image(size_x, size_y);
  anim_img.onload = function() {
    // Calls `animate` repeatedly until `interval` is cleared
    interval = setInterval(animate, 30);
  }
  anim_img.src = 'https://www.logomaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/education1.png';
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function animate() {
  // Re-draws the image at different positions on the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_size_x, canvas_size_y);
  if (x_icon < 0 || x_icon > canvas_size_x - size_x) { stepX *= -1; }
  if (y_icon < 0 || y_icon > canvas_size_y - size_y) { stepY *= -1; }
  x_icon += stepX;
  y_icon += stepY;
  ctx.drawImage(anim_img, x_icon, y_icon);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="180" style="border:solid 1px;"></canvas>
<button id="button">STOP</button>
```